# Reading XML from the web in Java

Tags: android

I have a given URL with specific IDs. I'm suppose to pass those IDs to this URL as argument and retrieve the XML in java. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go ahead by opening creating http connection, opening stream and reading data.
After you can parse you xml data.
Not that sure this is what you need.. Provide us with more details.

Comment: I get the idea what you are saying no. You meant to use this code here:http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html. Now i just need to retrieve specific nodes. Any clue?

Comment: Now i have the text of XML file saved in a string variable here:  URL yahoo = new URL("http://192.168.10.21:8080/trace/service/?key=123");
        URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
Now how would i parse the string variable. Thank you

Comment: XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(); XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser(); parser.setInput(input, "UTF-8"); parser.setInput(new StringReader(YOUR_STR_HERE));  while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) { String name = parser.getName();
  if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) { if (name.equals(GolfCourse.TAG_COURSE)) { // parse your data }

Answer (score 1):

Android uses HttpClient. You can create [simple GET with parameters](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e37).

For parsing XML you have both DOM and SAX parser on Android.

DOM reads whole document in memory and lets you manipulate it: [examples](http://www.exampledepot.com/search/luceneapi_node/dom)

SAX is stream oriented and is more usable on large XML documents where you would like to just get specific elements/attributes: [examples](http://www.exampledepot.com/search/luceneapi_node/sax)

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using this for XML functionality, XmlPullParser.

```
XmlPullParser newPullParser = Xml.newPullParser();
```